# https via htaaccess multiple website rule

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, htaccess, https

I'm using 2 websites on 2 domains. I'm loading correct website via htaaccess with rules as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*clothes\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:clotheseu]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*clothes\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Now I added SSL and **frontend/admin** area works from https url.

The problem is that when user is using OLD http address for `category/products/cms`, they are redirected 302 to homepage instead of correct page.

**Example:**

`http://clothes.eu/product.html` is redirected to: `https://clothes.eu` instead of `https://clothes.eu/product.html`

htaacces as above points to main domain: clothes.eu and all my product/category suffix is cut.

**I found Admin option: Auto-redirect to Base URL > 302 > this is probably doing this. but why this cuts all product/category suffix in url ? should I disable it ?**

Could somebode help me with the htaaccess rule to avoid category/product cut in URLs that come from http ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: for http->https you have to use rewrites, for magento store code, you have to set environmental variable.

Comment: Any example? What do you mean exactly? I disabled Auto-redirect to Base URL, and everything looks ok know. I hope so.